# String "NA" conflict with pandas na type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file and it contains value "NA"(a string named a country), and when I use fillna() function it will recognize string "NA" as pandas na type, how could I do?

files like this

```
aa.csv
1,2,3,4,5
NA,BA,CA,EA,AA

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("aa.csv")
clean = df.fillna("")
print(clean) 
print(df)
```

result is:

```
  1   2   3   4   5
0    BA  CA  EA  AA

    1   2   3   4   5
0 NaN  BA  CA  EA  AA
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952142/prevent-pandas-from-interpreting-na-as-nan-in-a-string

Comment: @Keatinge Thank you very much. I learned a lot by this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `na_filter` parameter as `False`

```
df = pd.read_csv("aa.csv", na_filter=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very useful for me