# How to not count "NA" as a string value and not empty cell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file with two columns; `country_name` and `alpha_2_code`. In the case of `Namibia`, the code is `NA`. While reading the file by default this cell is taken to be empty. After looking into the documentation, I understand `na_values` parameter can only be used to add *additional* values.
How do we count `NA` as a string value and not an empty cell here?

The format of the file is as:

```
country_name|country_code
Mexico      |MX
Namibia     |NA
```

Expected results for `df.describe()`:

```
      country_name|country_code
count: 2          |2
```

Actual results:

```
      country_name|country_code
count: 2          |1
```

Comment: I was writing the answer but found it is marked duplicated already. Here is the answer I have written regarding your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56540573/3129414

Comment: Thanks a ton @arsho! I did exactly the same:)