# Prevent Pandas read_csv from interpreting NA as NaN but retaining NaN for empty values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952142/prevent-pandas-from-interpreting-na-as-nan-in-a-string/33952294). I have a file named 'test.csv' with 'NA' as a value for `region`. I want to read this in as 'NA', not 'NaN'. However, there are missing values in other columns in test.csv, which I want to retain as 'NaN'. How can I do this?

```
# test.csv looks like this:
```

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
import pandas as pd
# This reads NA as NaN
df = pd.read_csv(test.csv)
df
    region  date    expenses
0   NaN   1/1/2019  53
1   EU    1/2/2019  NaN

# This reads NA as NA, but doesn't read missing expense as NaN
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', keep_default_na=False, na_values='_')
df
    region  date    expenses
0   NA    1/1/2019  53
1   EU    1/2/2019  

# What I want:
    region  date    expenses
0   NA    1/1/2019  53
1   EU    1/2/2019  NaN
```

The problem with adding the argument `keep_default_na=False` is that the second value for `expenses` does not get read in as `NaN`. So if I then try `pd.isnull(df['value'][1])` this is returned as `False`.

Comment: In that linked post the `null` values are represented by an underscore hence they set `na_values='_'`. In your case missing data appear to be represented by the empty string, so I'd go with `na_values=''` (in addition to `keep_default_na=False`) If that solves your problem then this is clearly a dup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, this works:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])
```

which gives:

```
  region      date  expenses
0     NA  1/1/2019      53.0
1     EU  1/2/2019       NaN
```

But I'd rather play safe, due to possible other `NaN` in other columns, and do

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df['region'] = df['region'].fillna('NA')
```

Answer (score 0):

when specifying `keep_default=False` all defaults values are not considered as nan so you should specify them:

use `keep_default_na=False, na_values= [‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’]`

Answer (score 0):

This approach work for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
co1 col2  col3  col4
a   b    c  d   e
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   3   4   5   NaN
```

I copied the value and created a list which are by default interpreted as NaN then comment out NA which I wanted to be interpreted as not NaN. This approach still treat other values as NaN except for NA.

```
#You can also create your own list of value that should be treated as NaN and 
# then pass the values to na_values and set keep_default_na=False.
        na_values = ["", 
                     "#N/A", 
                     "#N/A N/A", 
                     "#NA", 
                     "-1.#IND", 
                     "-1.#QNAN", 
                     "-NaN", 
                     "-nan", 
                     "1.#IND", 
                     "1.#QNAN", 
                     "<NA>", 
                     "N/A", 
        #              "NA", 
                     "NULL", 
                     "NaN", 
                     "n/a", 
                     "nan", 
                     "null"]
    
        df1 = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',na_values=na_values,keep_default_na=False )
    
              co1  col2  col3  col4
        a     b     c     d     e
        NaN  NA   NaN    NA   NaN
        2     3     4     5   NaN
```