# CSV file handling with Pandas for text comparison

Tags: python, pandas, csv, winmerge

I have this csv file called input.csv

```
KEY;Rate;BYld;DataAsOfDate
CH04;0.719;0.674;2020-01-29
CH03;1.5;0.148;2020-01-29
```

then I execute the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', sep=";")
input_df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=";")
```

and get the following output.csv file

```
KEY;Rate;BYld;DataAsOfDate
CH04;0.7190000000000001;0.674;2020-01-29
CH03;1.5;0.14800000000000002;2020-01-29
```

I was hoping for and expecting an output like this:
(to be able to use a tool like [winmerge.org](https://winmerge.org) to detect real differences on each row)
(my real code truly modifies the dataframe - this stack overflow example is for demonstration only)

```
KEY;Rate;BYld;DataAsOfDate
CH04;0.719;0.674;2020-01-29
CH03;1.5;0.148;2020-01-29
```

What is the idiomatic way with to achieve such an unmodified output with Pandas?

Comment: I guess that depends on what you're going to do with your csv apart from reading/writing. How about reading it into pandas treating each columns as string instead of float/int...?

Comment: That is a possibility, thank you, I'll explore that.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not use traditional rounding to so as to prevent problems with bankers rounding. However, if being close is not a problem you could use the round function and replace the "2" with whichever number you would like to round to

```
d = [['CH04',0.719,0.674,'2020-01-29']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns = (['KEY', 'Rate', 'BYld', 'DataAsOfDate']))
df['Rate'] = df['Rate'].apply(lambda x : round(x, 2))
df
```

Comment: Thank you for having a look and trying to help. The issue I have with this approach is that I don't know the decimal specificity of each column (my real example has 38 columns and I prefer to not go through each and figure out the specifity) - I hope that makes sense!

Comment: For that you have a couple options, if you have 38 columns and one time would look to see that 12 are 1 decimal and 26 are 2 decimals (just for example) you could change the code slightly to resolve multiple at a single time.  df[['Rate', 'BYld']] = df[['Rate', 'BYld']].apply(lambda x : round(x, 2)) this would resolve both columns at once so if you studied the data you might be able to still use the round option.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Prokos idea I changed the code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', dtype='str',sep=";")
input_df.to_csv('str_output.csv', sep=";", index=False)
```

and that meets the requirement - all columns come out unchanged.

Comment: Another thing that I had to do in a similar vein, to keep N/A values from changing between in and out - [33952142](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952142/prevent-pandas-from-interpreting-na-as-nan-in-a-string)