How can I prevent text from being classified as "nan" in pandas dataframe
I am making use of a pandas dataframe to compile a CSV file from an Excel (xlsx) file. One of my columns contains only two letters and some are "NA". When I simply add this value to a dataframe, the value in my CSV file displays "nan".
The workaround I have for this seems to be inefficient, although it is working.
# Just adding this here for more context
xlsx_file = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
sheet_df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file, 'Sheet1')

# Force values to text
sheet_df['initials'] = sheet_df['initials'].astype(str)

if sheet_df['initials'] == 'nan':
    initials_value = 'NA'
else:
    initials_value = sheet_df['initials']

Is there a better way I can do this?
Thanks!

Try using pd.read_excel(..., na_values=[])

Thanks. After posting the suggestions displayed two similar posts. I used keep_default_na=False, which solved the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952142/prevent-pandas-from-interpreting-na-as-nan-in-a-string).

Great, that's why it's best to search before posting ;) Good luck on your project
