# Why df have '.0' when I to txt?

Tags: python, pandas

```
t=pd.DataFrame(tree_pre)

t.fillna('',inplace=True)

print(t)

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 8
0          55                      
1      30                  70      
2  25                  65      85  
3              60                  
4                  64
```

but when I to txt

```
t.to_csv('2020.txt',sep='\t',index=False,header=False)
```

The txt have '.0'

```
    55.0                        
30.0                    70.0
```

25.0                    65.0        85.0
            60.0
                64.0

Why df have '.0' when I to txt?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092671/python-pandas-output-dataframe-to-csv-with-integers

Comment: Related: [Prevent pandas from automatically inferring type in read_csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101113/prevent-pandas-from-automatically-inferring-type-in-read-csv)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a format specifier, this should work:

```py
t.to_csv('2020.txt',sep='\t',index=False,header=False,float_format='%.0f')
```

Comment: didn't know that, I thought it was just due to the program they opened it in.

Answer (score 1):

> Why df have '.0' when I to txt?

numpy.nan is an instance of `float` so any column with nan will be a float type.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.nan,np.nan,4],[4,np.nan,5,np.nan,6]])
>>> df
   0    1    2   3  4
0  1  2.0  NaN NaN  4
1  4  NaN  5.0 NaN  6

>>> df.dtypes
0      int64
1    float64
2    float64
3    float64
4      int64
dtype: object

>>> isinstance(df.iloc[0,2],float)
True

>>> df.fillna('',inplace=True)
>>> df.iloc[0,1]
2.0
>>>
```